# Is it possible for Mockito.when(X).thenReturn(Y) to return a Set<Optional<MyClass>>?

Tags: spring, testing, mockito, set

**The Gist**

I was writing some tests with Spring Boot, JUnit5, and Mockito. Try as I might, I can't quite figure out how to get it to return a Set of Optionals. I've scoured the net and SO to the best of my abilities already.

**Background**

I have a JPA Repo method that returns a Set<Optional> for one of its query methods. I can test all the other query methods related to the specific service they're being called by except for this one.

When the repo returns a single item, I use:

```
MyClass myObj = new MyClass();
Mockito.when(repo.findByX(X)).thenReturn(Optional.of(myObj));
```

**What I want**

Something of this ilk:

```
Mockito.when(repository.findAllByX(X)).thenReturn(Set(Optional.of(myObj)));
```

The Set would really just consist of the single object for the purpose of the test, but given the constraints of the repo method, it has to be a Set and cannot just be the object itself.

**Plea**

Mockito has served me well thus far, but I have run into the problem over and over that mocking the repo means that nothing will actually be saved (and thus auto-generated ids don't function). And if it would save changes to the mock repo, that would make life so much easier. So, if there's a better way to test services that modify repositories, I'd love to know about it.

Thanks for any help and guidance.

Comment: Try `Set.of(Optional.of(myObj))`.

Comment: @StefanGolubović Tried it; getting the following error: ```"Cannot resolve method 'of' in 'Set'"```. I guess, Set isn't as special as Optional.

Comment: Which version of Java are you using? Have you tried creating a set and then returning it? For example: `Set<Optional<MyClass>> set = new HashSet<>(); set.add(Optional.of(myObj)); Mockito.when(...).thenReturn(set);`. Or [any other way](https://www.baeldung.com/java-initialize-hashset).

Comment: This worked, my friend! Thanks! Make it into and an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible. All you need to do is create a set and pass it as parameter.

If you're using Java 9+, you can use [`of`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Set.html#of(E)) factory method(s) to create a set.

```java
Mockito.when(repository.findAllByX(X)).thenReturn(Set.of(Optional.of(myObj)));
```

For lower versions of Java, there are many other ways:

1. just create a set and add an element

```java
Set<Optional<MyClass>> set = new HashSet<>(); 
set.add(Optional.of(myObj));
Mockito.when(repository.findAllByX(X)).thenReturn(set);
```

2. using [Arrays.asList](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#asList-T...-)

```java
Set<Optional<MyClass>> set = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(Optional.of(myObj));
Mockito.when(repository.findAllByX(X)).thenReturn(set);
```

3. using anonymous class

```java
Set<Optional<MyClass>> set = new HashSet<String>(){{
    add(Optional.of(myObj));
}};
Mockito.when(repository.findAllByX(X)).thenReturn(set);
```

4. using Stream (Java 8+)

```java
Set<Optional<MyClass>> set = Stream.of(Optional.of(myObj))
  .collect(Collectors.toCollection(HashSet::new));
Mockito.when(repository.findAllByX(X)).thenReturn(set);
```

5. using 3rd party library

Check [Google Guava](https://github.com/google/guava), [Apache Commons Collections](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/), [Eclipse Collections](https://www.eclipse.org/collections/) or any other that you run into.